# how to handle click listener of EditText drawableRight icon in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-vectordrawable

How to handle Click event on EditText DrawableRight in android Kotlin? 
Please find my code :

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/userpwd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_left"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline_right"
            android:inputType="textWebPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/login_form_details_dark"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/login_form_details_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/et_cursor"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/login_form_details_dark"
            android:tooltipText="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_eye"
            android:drawableTint="@color/login_form_details_dark"
            android:textColorLink="@color/login_form_details"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will i know how to do it in Java you can get the main idea

```
editText.setDrawableClickListener(new       DrawableClickListener() { public void onClick(DrawablePosition target){ switch (target){ case LEFT: //Do something here break; default: break; } } });
```